# Pattern Matching & Replacement / Cleaning of Data in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, geospatial, data-cleaning

I'm looking to plot geospatial data, thus I require coordinates. The information I've been provided is very messy and I need a good system to convert a vector of coordinates in multiple formats into one useful format as per below:

Input:

```
- lat <- c("41º12'23.33''", "40º39'15.6'", "41 10 589", "38 31 10.6",
   "38.720647") 
 - lon <- c("8º19'40.66''", "7º52'31.95'", "8 37 832", "8    54 17.0",
   "-9.22522")
```

Output:

```
- lat <- c(41.122333, 40.39156, 41.10589, 38.31106, 38.720647)
 - lon <- c(8.194066, 7.523195, 8.37832, 8.54170, -9.22522)
```

Does anyone have a creative solution? Any response is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried any code yet? Please add to the question if any to see what you have already tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
lat <- c("41º12'23.33''", "40º39'15.6'", "41 10 589", "38 31 10.6", "38.720647")
lon <- c("8º19'40.66''", "7º52'31.95'", "8 37 832", "8 54 17.0", "-9.22522")

gsub(" ", "", sub("\\s", ".", gsub("º|\\'|\\.", " ", lat)))
[1] "41.122333" "40.39156"  "41.10589"  "38.31106"  "38.720647"

gsub(" ", "", sub("\\s", ".", gsub("º|\\'|\\.", " ", lon)))
[1] "8.194066" "7.523195" "8.37832"  "8.54170"  "-9.22522"
```

1.: replace all `º`, `'` and `.` with a white space

2.: replace the first white space with a decimal point

3.: replace all remaining spaces by `""` to have your strings pasted together again

Comment: Brilliant, I was trying to figure out how to work with all those cases together.

Comment: Thanks! At first I was working with `gsub("\\D", " ", lat)` to only keep the digits and replace all other stuff with spaces, but that made the `-` be replaced as well. If someone knows how to replace everything except digits and the minus sign by whitespace, please enlighten me. :) That might make this code easier to adapt I think. :)

Answer (score 1):

With Base `R` could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
lat <- c("41º12'23.33''", "40º39'15.6'", "41 10 589", "38 31 10.6", "38.720647")

for (i in lat) 
{
  i <- gsub("º| ","@",i)
  i <- gsub("'|\\.","",i)
  i <- gsub("@",".",i)
  print(i)
}
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "41.122333"
[1] "40.39156"
[1] "41 10 589"
[1] "38 31 106"
[1] "38720647"
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will also work:

```
# DATA
lat <- c("41º12'23.33''", "40º39'15.6'", "41 10 589", "38 31 10.6", "38.720647")
lon <- c("8º19'40.66''", "7º52'31.95'", "8 37 832", "8 54 17.0", "-9.22522")


# FUNCTION
convert_coordinates <- function(x) {
  splits <- x %>% strsplit(. , "º| |[.]|'") # Remove unwanted punctuation. Note that you can add more characters to replace here, just separate them with a |
  splits <- lapply(splits, function(x){x[!x ==""]}) # Remove any empty strings
  output <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(splits)) {
    output[i] <- paste0(splits[[i]][1], ".", paste0(splits[[i]][2:(length(splits[[i]]))], collapse=""), collapse="")
  }
  return(output)
}

# RESULTS
convert_coordinates(lat)
# [1] "41.122333" "40.39156"  "41.10589"  "38.31106"  "38.720647"

convert_coordinates(lon)
# [1] "8.194066" "7.523195" "8.37832"  "8.54170"  "-9.22522"
```